# Create an ArrayList with empty objects using lambda

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to create an ArrayList of objects that have an id and an empty list using streams. I tried different ways but none seams to work. If someone can give me some hits will help me a lot. 
Here is the code that I want to convert to Java 8:

```
    this.registers = new ArrayList<Supplier>();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.numberOfSuppliers; i++) {
        Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
        supplier.setSupplierNumber(i);
        supplier.setMaterials(new ArrayList<Warehouse>());
        this.registers.add(supplier);
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unless this is just an exercise in Streams, don't convert to Streams. The `for` loop is good as it is. You will gain nothing by converting to Streams, not even clarity or simplicity of code. In my opinion, it'll actually be less clean/simple (see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42602337/5221149)).

Comment: Yes, it's just an exercise. But thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider adding a constructor to Supplier that takes the id as a parameter, and initializes the list of materials, so you don't have to expose a setter.  Then the solution using either the loop or streams becomes much simpler.

```
public void buildSuppliersWithLoop()
{
    ArrayList<Supplier> registers = new ArrayList<>()
    int numberOfSuppliers = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSuppliers; i++)
    {
        registers.add(new Supplier(i));
    }
}

public void buildSuppliersWithStream()
{
    int numberOfSuppliers = 100;
    List<Supplier> registers = IntStream.range(0, numberOfSuppliers)
            .mapToObj(Supplier::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public class Supplier
{
    private int number;
    private List<Warehouse> materials;

    public Supplier(int number)
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.materials = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

public class Warehouse
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not my preferred approach (I think the for loop is fine here), but in streams you can do this:

```
this.registers = IntStream.range(0, this.numberOfSuppliers)
         .map(i -> {
                       Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
                       supplier.setSupplierNumber(i);
                       supplier.setMaterials(new ArrayList<Warehouse>());
                       return supplier;
         })
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: *Caveat:* That creates a `List<Supplier>`, not an `ArrayList<Supplier>`. If an `ArrayList` is required, replace `Collectors.toList()` with `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<Supplier>::new)`.

Comment: I believe you need to use mapToObj here, instead of map, as map returns an IntStream, not a Stream.

Comment: You can also extract the creation of the Supplier object to a different method to improve readability.